# How to forcefully remove fuse[.glusterfs] related entries from /proc/self/mounts when "umount -f/-l" won't work?

Tags: mount, fuse

After the auxilliary process(es?) died and the directory in question is empty, it's impossible to get rid of the entry in `/proc/self/mounts` (options `-l` and `-f` don't help).  IMHO the below should not be GlusterFS specific:

```
# mount /mnt/shared
/sbin/mount.glusterfs: according to mtab, GlusterFS is already mounted on /mnt/shared
# umount /mnt/shared
umount: /mnt/shared: not mounted.
# grep "shared fuse.glusterfs" /proc/self/mounts | sed -e 's|.*:|example.org:|'
example.org:/shared /mnt/shared fuse.glusterfs rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,max_read=131072 0 0
```

There *is* a (quick and dirty) **workaround** in case it's possible to rename `/mnt/shared`: 1. mount the contents somewhere else (say, `/mnt/shared.tmp`), 2. `mv /mnt/shared /mnt/shared.old`, and 3. `ln -s /mnt/shared.tmp /mnt/shared`.  Of course, this needs to be undone once (read: *before*) the machine gets rebooted.

Given that the `/proc/self/mounts` entry in question should be *inherited* (the current "self" refers to a shell and the filesystem originally got mounted during startup by means of an `/etc/fstab` entry), is there a way to identify where that entry "originated" and get rid of it "in the proper context"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `fusermount -u /mount_point`

Comment: `fusermount -u [z] ...` returns an `Invalid argument` error in the above case.

Comment: So I'm not sure what exactly is going on but at one point `fusermount -u` worked, after kill -9 -ing everything (sshfs, code) and restarting autofs a few times. I couldn't replicate what I did but I was ready to restart the computer as if it was running Windoze. The `Invalid argument` message I got after the unmount was successful.